# Using jPicEdt for graphic?

Tags: graphics, diagrams

I'm using the jPicEdt to make the diagram and also generate the LaTeX code. I'm trying to increase the size of diagram?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp][width=0.5mm]
\centering
\begin{picture}(160,90)(0,0)
\linethickness{0.3mm}
\multiput(10,30)(0.12,0.3){167}{\line(0,1){0.3}}
\multiput(30,80)(1.57,0.12){83}{\line(1,0){1.57}}
\multiput(10,30)(1.57,0.12){83}{\line(1,0){1.57}}
\multiput(140,40)(0.12,0.3){167}{\line(0,1){0.3}}
\put(90,25){\makebox(0,0)[cc]{}}
\put(8,25){\makebox(0,0)[cc]{$\alpha$}}
\put(145,35){\makebox(0,0)[cc]{$\beta$}}
\put(23.5,82){\makebox(0,0)[cc]{$\gamma$}}
\put(165,90){\makebox(0,0)[cc]{$\epsilon$}}
\put(130,25){\makebox(0,0)[cc]{}}
\end{picture}
\caption{Three Dimensional Schematic Diagram of Physical Problem}
\label{fig:1.1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's really strange that the program outputs a line made up with short segments: you get a very jagged line. The `picture` mode is able to to much better.

Comment: Yea i know but now I'm trying to increase the size of figure.

Comment: Just say `\setlength{\unitlength}{2pt}` before `\begin{picture}` and you'll double its size. But you're using the wrong tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `picture` environment exported from jPicEdt is really peculiar, as it builds a line by placing multiple short segments next to each other; the result is a jagged line.

You can resize your picture by changing `\unitlength`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\setlength{\unitlength}{2pt} % double the size
\begin{picture}(160,90)(0,0)
\linethickness{0.3mm}
\multiput(10,30)(0.12,0.3){167}{\line(0,1){0.3}}
\multiput(30,80)(1.57,0.12){83}{\line(1,0){1.57}}
\multiput(10,30)(1.57,0.12){83}{\line(1,0){1.57}}
\multiput(140,40)(0.12,0.3){167}{\line(0,1){0.3}}
\put(90,25){\makebox(0,0)[cc]{}}
\put(8,25){\makebox(0,0)[cc]{$\alpha$}}
\put(145,35){\makebox(0,0)[cc]{$\beta$}}
\put(23.5,82){\makebox(0,0)[cc]{$\gamma$}}
\put(165,90){\makebox(0,0)[cc]{$\epsilon$}}
\put(130,25){\makebox(0,0)[cc]{}}
\end{picture}
\caption{Three Dimensional Schematic Diagram of Physical Problem}
\label{fig:1.1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If you want to have a stated width you have to do some computations; your picture is 160 units wide (the standard unit is 1pt); if you want to scale the picture to be, say, 8cm, do the conversion:

> 8*72.27/2.54 = 227.62

is the desired width in points; since 227.62/160 = 1.42 (these are approximate values), you want

```
\setlength{\unitlength}{1.42pt}
```

It would be possible to make the computation automatic.

Here's a proper way to draw the diagram with the help of the `pict2e` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pict2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\setlength{\unitlength}{1.42pt}
\begin{picture}(160,90)(0,0)
\linethickness{0.3mm}
\Line(10,30)(30,80)
\Line(30,80)(160,90)
\Line(10,30)(140,40)
\Line(140,40)(160,90)
\put(90,25){\makebox(0,0)[cc]{}}
\put(8,25){\makebox(0,0)[cc]{$\alpha$}}
\put(145,35){\makebox(0,0)[cc]{$\beta$}}
\put(23.5,82){\makebox(0,0)[cc]{$\gamma$}}
\put(165,90){\makebox(0,0)[cc]{$\epsilon$}}
\put(130,25){\makebox(0,0)[cc]{}}
\end{picture}
\caption{Three Dimensional Schematic Diagram of Physical Problem}
\label{fig:1.1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

No jagged lines.

[image]

Comment: \Line(10,30)(30,80)
\Line(30,80)(160,90)
\Line(10,30)(140,40)
\Line(140,40)(160,90) please explain these lines

Comment: The `\Line` command is followed by two sets of coordinates; the first is the starting point, the second is the end point and a segment is drawn to connect them. I just computed them expanding what your `\multiput` did.

Comment: I generate this code from jPicEdt software. Now I make the circle but it's also Jagged.

Comment: I want to share the circle code with you but it's too length how could I share with that code?

Comment: I am trying to share the BOX code but how could I share it.